# Is some thing wrong with the epsilon-delta definition of limit??

Tags: limits, continuity, definition, epsilon-delta

In the epsilon-delta definition of limit which is:

> For all $\epsilon>0$ there exists a $\delta>0$ such that, whenever $|x-a|<\delta$ then $|f(x)-L|<\epsilon$ .

Now since $\epsilon$ is given and it should be proven that there is some $\delta$ for the given $\epsilon$, then I think the rest of the definition should have been:

> $|f(x)-L|<\epsilon \implies |x-a|<\delta$ .

Please tell me whether I'm right or not.

Comment: Downvoting seems inappropriate. OP has *thought about the matter* and happens to have reached an incorrect conclusion.

Comment: I believe you are confusing the notion of hypothesis/conclusion with the idea of "$\epsilon$ is given$"/"$\delta$ is constructed from it".

Comment: Note that this is **not** the definition of limit. Without adding $0<|x-a|$ to the condition, the conclusion can hold for all $\epsilon$ only if $f(a)=L$.

Comment: @Jack, check also [this answer on MO](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/88540/how-to-motivate-and-present-epsilon-delta-proofs-to-undergraduates) discussing this topic and ways to (intuitively) present it/teach it etc..

Comment: @Jack, also [this question on math.se](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/331445/the-epsilon-delta-definition-of-continuity) is directly related to your question (plus it gives some intuitive answers)

Answer (score 21):

Your proposed definition

> For all $\epsilon > 0$ there exists a $\delta > 0$ such that $|f(x)-L| < \epsilon \implies |x-a| < \delta$.

has quite a few problems with it.

For instance, let $f(x) = 0$ and consider $\displaystyle\lim_{x \to 0}f(x)$. In any reasonable definition of a limit, we should have $\displaystyle\lim_{x \to 0}0 = 0$. So, we need to prove:

> For all $\epsilon > 0$ there exists a $\delta > 0$ such that $|0-0| < \epsilon \implies |x-0| < \delta$

Unfortunately, $|0-0| < \epsilon$ is true for any $x \in \mathbb{R}$, but $|x-0| < \delta$ is false for any $x > \delta$. Thus, there is never a $\delta > 0$ which makes "$|0-0| < \epsilon \implies |x-0| < \delta$" a true statement. Therefore, by your proposed definition, $\displaystyle\lim_{x \to 0}0$ is not $0$.

Comment: This does not explain why it is phrased that way. if the alternative definition (as suggested by OP) has problems, why this (working) definition is phrased like this? Should it be phrased otherwise and if so how, in order to not have this *ambiguity*?

Comment: Or why not have the OP's definition and add this *problematic case* of $f(x)=0$ as special case (like it is done for $0! = 1$)? Or why not say "*for all $\delta$ there is an $\epsilon$ ..*" etc.., since this is what is done here?

Comment: @NikosM.: there would be literally uncountable number of special case, as it's trivial to construct plenty more (here are some more $\sin(x),\exp(x),\tan(x),x^{-1}$). As for ambiguity, this definition can be directly translated into a logical statement, so where is the ambiguity?

Comment: @Gina, thanks for the comemnt, but it does not provide the kind and depth of explanation (and intuitive understanding) i would like (of course the OP will select an answer), see my answer for what i would like to have as an answer to this

Answer (score 6):

The way I used to think about it is this: it is something like a Space Invaders game (if you remember those).  The enemy is firing epsilons at you.  For each epsilon that comes at you, you have to be able to counter by finding a delta such that for every $x$ such that $|x−a|<δ$, then $|f(x)−L|< \epsilon$

If some epsilon arrives such that you can't find a delta, *you lose*.

For example, suppose that $f(x) = 1$ for $x < 0.5$ and $f(x) = 2$ for $x \geq 0.5$.  (Yes, a step function.)

Look at $a = 0.5$ and   Try $L = 1.5$

Suppose $\epsilon = 1$ arrives.  Then you're OK because you can reply with $\delta = 0.1$ (for example).  For values of $x$ between $0.4$ and $0.6$, the values for $f(x)$ are either $1$ or $2$, so $|f(x) - L|$ is always $0.5$, and it is true that $ |f(x) - L| < \epsilon = 1$.

But if $\epsilon  = 0.2$ arrives, then it doesn't matter how small a $\delta$ you reply with, you can't get 
$|f(x) - L| < \epsilon = 0.2$  for all the $x$ between $0.5 - \delta$ and $0.5 + \delta$.

So *you lose*, and the limit isn't $L = 1.5$.

With a little bit more effort you can demonstrate that it doesn't matter what value of $L$ you try for the limit, if $\epsilon = 0.2$ arrives, *you lose*.

So in this example the limit of $f(x)$ as $x$ tends to $0.5$ doesn't exist.  Intuitively, of course it doesn't exist, but we want to see how the textbook definition works out for this example.

The definition in the textbooks is correct.  It is hard to understand, but maybe the Space Invaders analogy helps.

Comment: Your answer is a good one, except that the definition as written in the question is not completely correct.

Comment: I like this as an explanation of why limits are defined the way they are, but is it possible to extend or adapt the analogy to explain why the alternate definition proposed in the question doesn't work? Like, what if the enemy fired $\delta$s instead of $\epsilon$s? Why wouldn't that lead to a useful definition of a limit?

Comment: This answer too, takes the $\delta$'s to be *generated* (an analogy) **first** and **then** the $\epsilon$'s

Comment: @NikosM.: You're absolutely wrong. Read his answer again; which explicitly says that ε comes first and then you have to generate a suitable δ.

Comment: @user21820, yeah ok, acquired speed. Still the negative comments on my answer do **not** address the issue at hand.

Comment: @user21820, saying plainly it is wrong (or completely wrong or absolutely wrong) is **not** good enough. **Why** it is wrong specifically and intuitively/practically. Non-adherence to "conventions" is also **not** good enough. Personally i like to have an as deep understanding as possible, it is easy for me to copy-paste syntax here and there, but this is *not what i would like* as an answer (even if my answer **is** eventually wrong)

Comment: @NikosM.: We have adequately specified what is wrong with your statements. For example here, I explicitly said that "ε comes first and then you have to generate a suitable δ". And no one is criticizing your statements based on convention at all. If you want a more in depth explanation, ask a new question, but don't pretend to know what you are talking about, and we will be glad to address your issues in understanding.

Comment: @user21820, no you are wrong sorry, $\epsilon$ comes first in the definition (we already know that, the OP already knows that) **but not** in the practice of the definition (among other things) and this is tne point of the question and which i (tried to) explicitly address in my answer. **Why** it is like this (or phrased like this) and afaic no one addressed this to the point

Comment: @user21820, Btw i am not terribly eager to answer this question and just decided to do it **after** i saw a couple of answers and **after** i commented that it is a nice question and indeed i did not take the time to reflect upon it myself (when learning about limits, when i was a student). OK? Noone is terribly happy to get into debate with a formed group of people (but if needed it should be done)

Comment: @NikosM.: Firstly, we're not a formed group and I know none of the other answerers or commenters. Secondly, I suspect you do not understand logic, which is why you keep talking about "in the practice of the definition" generating δ first and then ε. Finally, there is no debate in mathematics, once assumptions are all stated. A proof is either correct or wrong. Any proof of a limit must generate δ that depends on ε, never the other way around. Anything that reverses the order is not a proof. If you can't accept that then there's nothing more I can say.

Comment: @user21820, [first answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/850019/139391) addresses exactly this (as re-phrased by OP), generate a $\delta$ from $\epsilon$, ok i dont want to take this into a chat, if you want add more comments in my answer

Comment: @user21820, the OP, as you, as me (and most of the people in this post) already **know** the definiton, what is asked is an explanation and understanding of the definition (and as such an understanding and explanation of the practice underlying the application of the definition), i hope this is clear enough (ps there are many debates in mathematics i.e constructivism, relaims etc..)

Comment: @NikosM.: Whatever you say, your answers show very clearly that you do not grasp logic. So if you don't want to learn, I really have had enough.

Answer (score 6):

Firstly, I suggest you learn logic first, otherwise it is very difficult to understand a lot of things rigorously. It seems you do not understand scoping of quantifiers, which is why the English phrasing, although unambiguous, is not clear to you.

Secondly, there is a mistake in the definition as you have written it.

Let me write the correct definition in terms of its logical structure, which I suggest you do for definitions and theorems whose structure you do not understand perfectly.

**Limit Definition**

$\lim_{x \to a} f(x) = L$ iff:

For any $ε > 0$:

For some $δ > 0$:

For any $x \in Dom(f)$:

If $0 < | x - a | < δ$:

$| f(x) - L | < ε$

Let us go through it properly. The limit of a function $f$ at $a$ being $L$ means that no matter what positive $ε$ you give me, I can give you a positive $δ$ such that the **pair** $(ε,δ)$ has a certain property. That property is that no matter what $x$ you give me from the domain of $f$, the **triple** $(ε,δ,x)$ has a certain (other) property, which is that if the distance between $x$ and $a$ is less than $δ$, then the distance between $f(x)$ and $L$ is less than $ε$. Note that this last property says nothing at all if the triple currently in consideration is such that $x$ and $a$ are at least $δ$ apart.

So why is it defined this way? Let us give a more intuitive sense of a limit. We can look at a landscape through a window. If we look through at a landscape through a smaller window, we will surely not see more, and for most natural landscapes the region we can see will become more and more 'bland' as the window shrinks (about a fixed centre). (At first we see a tree with branches and leaves, later we see only a leaf, later we see only a patch of a single colour, green.) If the entire region that we see gets closer and closer in colour to green as the window shrinks, then we can say that the limit colour at the 'centre' of the shrinking window is green. This is not quite the mathematical definition yet. Imagine that there is a minuscule dot at the centre of the window, so we cannot see the colour of the landscape there. The limit is still said to exist. But what does "closer and closer" mean? It means that no matter what positive error margin we desire, as the window shrinks to zero size, eventually the colour of the region we can see will always remain near the limit to within that error margin. Consider the landscape to be a function $f$, where $f(x)$ is the colour of the region that can be seen when we look through point $x$ on the window. Call the centre of the window $a$. Consider the window size to be $δ$ and the error margin to be $ε$. Then our above notion means that $f$ has a limit colour $c$ at its centre $a$ if and only if, for any positive $ε$, we can find a positive window size $δ$ such that once it shrinks smaller than that size, all the colours $f(x)$ we can see through it ($| x - a | < δ$) are within $ε$ of the colour $c$ ($| f(x) - c | < ε$).

Now if the window has its centre exactly on the boundary of an object which is of a different colour than its background, the limit colour will not exist because no matter how small we make the window, we will see a little bit of the object and a little of the background. This corresponds to a jump discontinuity at $a$.

Also, we couldn't see the colour of the landscape behind the centre of the window. It could be the same colour as the limit colour, in which case $f$ is continuous at $a$. But it could be a different colour, in which case $f$ has a removable discontinuity at $a$.

Finally, the landscape could have infinite detail that keeps varying widely between colours (within the window) no matter how small we shrink the window. A mathematical example would be if $f(x) = \sin(\frac{1}{x})$ and $a = 0$. In this case $f$ also has no limit at $a$, and the discontinuity is neither a jump discontinuity nor a removable discontinuity.

Lastly, note that this analogy with windows and landscapes immediately applies to the concept of continuity in general metric spaces. After all, we would have to define what distance between two colours means, but the idea is very natural.

Comment: Related to pointwise continuity is uniform continuity, pointwise convergence and uniform convergence, which when written out to make the logical structure explicit, will clearly show how the order of the quantifiers determine the meaning. See http://math.stackexchange.com/a/813372/21820.

Comment: +1, this is nice analysis, this was the content of my answer too, to elucidate the **scope of the quantifiers** (as in this answer) **and** also link this to the **practice of the definition** (which raised some negative comments btw)

Comment: @NikosM.: No; it is completely different from your answer, as has been pointed out.

Answer (score 0):

The alternative epsilon-delta sentence does describe a notable property of functions, but that property is not continuity or the existence of a limit.  The logical formula

> $Q(L,a)$ = "For all $\epsilon>0$ there exists a $\delta>0$ such that ($|f(x)-L|<\epsilon \implies |x-a|<\delta$)"

says that "any limit of $f$ at any other point is different from $L$".

Imitating the definition of continuity, by requiring that the formula $Q(L,a)$ holds with $L=f(a)$ at all $a$, characterizes functions $f$ for which *the closure of the graph of $f$ is injective*. The closure of $f$ could be a relation and not a function, but injectivity continues to make sense (for every $y$, if $aRy$ and $bRy$ then $a=b$).

This characterization is true for functions from one metric space to another.