# Prove that the sequence $[f_n]_{n \in N}$, $f_n(x)=\frac{x^{2n}}{1+x^{2n}}$ converges uniformly on $x \in [1+\delta,\infty[$

Tags: convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence

I've been asked to prove that the sequence $[f_n]_{n \in N}$ with $f_{n}(x)=\frac{x^{2n}}{1+x^{2n}}$ converges uniformly on $x \in [1+\delta,\infty[$ where $\delta > 0 $.

So far I've found that $f(x)=0$ for $x \in ]-1,1[$, $f(x)=\frac{1}{2}$ for $x=\pm 1$ and $f(x)=1$ for $x \notin [-1,1]$.
I have calculated the distance between each of them and found it to be $\frac{1}{2}$. It was 0 for $x=\pm 1$.
I am told, that I need to prove it using some sort of epsilon/delta proof, however I've been unsuccesful so far.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I suspect you also have a problem in understanding nested quantifiers. See http://math.stackexchange.com/a/813372/21820 for an explanation of uniform convergence and logical structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

Note that $\frac{x^{2n}}{1+x^{2n}} = 1 - \frac{1}{1+x^{2n}} \in 1-\left[0,\frac{1}{1+(1+δ)^{2n}}\right]$ for any $x \in [1+δ,\infty)$.

So it suffices to show that $\frac{1}{1+(1+δ)^{2n}} \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$.

Comment: Perfect. That would be the same as proving that a delta exists such that $\varepsilon >\frac{1}{(1+\delta)^{2n}}$. Correct?

Comment: @O.T.: Not sure what you mean. Uniform convergence does not have any delta; it's that for any error margin, from a certain point onwards in the sequence of **functions** it is close to the pointwise limit (to within the error margin).

Comment: @O.T.: I think I get your question. No of course not. $δ$ is **given** in your question right at the start; you can't change it. I said "as $n \to \infty$", which is exactly what you want (see my previous comment). You should learn to think in terms of asymptotic behaviour, not just formal definitions; anyway the last line in my answer says "when $n$ is big enough, $\frac{1}{1+(1+δ)^{2n}}$ would be small enough". No matter how small you want the latter, when $n$ is big enough you will get what you want.

Comment: Yea, that was my question. Eventually I figured, that I could just isolate N in this equation $\frac{1}{1+(1+\delta)^{2N}}<\varepsilon$.

Comment: @O.T.: Correct. $δ$ is a constant so you can find right at the beginning some natural $N$ such that $\frac{1}{1+(1+δ)^{2n}}<ε$ for any natural $n \ge N$.